# Javascript Pop up no longer shows on webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a pop up that originally showed on every webpage. After some modification to include the use of cookies to stop the webpage loading every single session, the pop up no longer shows. I can't figure out why and after extensive testing, research and just straight up asking for help I've concluded I do not have enough of an understanding on the subject.

If anyone is able to help me understand why its not working and help with a solution.

```
<div id='popup' style="display:none">
        <div class='cnt223'>
            <h1>Important Notice</h1>
            <p>
                Test!
                <br />
                <br />
                <a href='' class='close' style="color:green">OK</a>
                <a href='' class='goBack' style="color:red">KO</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function setCookie(cname, cvalue) {
            window.document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue;
        }

        function getCookie(cname) {
            var ca = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie).split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i].trim().split('=');
                if (cname == c[0] && c.length > 1) {
                    return c[1];
                }
            }
            return "";
        }

        function checkCookie() {
            if (getCookie("ageverification") == "") {
                $('#popup').show();
                $('#popup a.close').click(function ( event ) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('#popup').hide();
                    setCookie("ageverification", 'true');
                });
                $('#popup a.goBack').click(function ( event ) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    goBack();
                });
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        function goBack() {
            window.history.go(-2);
        }
        checkCookie();
```

**CSS "This is just on the same HTML page for now"**

```
<style type="text/css">
    #overlay {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #000;
        filter:alpha(opacity=70);
        -moz-opacity:0.7;
        -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
        opacity: 0.7;
        z-index: 100;
        display: none;
    }
    .cnt223 a{
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .popup{
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 101;
    }
    .cnt223{
        min-width: 600px;
        width: 600px;
        min-height: 150px;
        margin: 100px auto;
        background: #f3f3f3;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 103;
        padding: 15px 35px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #000;
    }
    .cnt223 p{
        clear: both;
        color: #555555;
        /* text-align: justify; */
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    .cnt223 p a{
        color: #d91900;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .cnt223 .x{
        float: right;
        height: 35px;
        left: 22px;
        position: relative;
        top: -25px;
        width: 34px;
    }
    .cnt223 .x:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: according to your code, if you already have the 'ageverification' cookie set, then you'll never get the popup to show.

Comment: I have cleared the cookies from my browser and attempted to reload it, but still nothing has shown. Could it be an issue with how ive told it to set a cookie? its searching for something that isnt there? would setting it to search for ageverification == null sort the issue?

Comment: write `document.cookie` in the console, what do you get ?

Comment: language=en-gb; currency=USD; language=en-gb; currency=USD; OCSESSID=42797d100b72401bd20c6fe374; __atuvc=5%7C34%2C34%7C35%2C83%7C36%2C18%7C37
Its not showing ageverification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the element with id "popup" nested within (a child of) the element with id "overlay" ? If it is, the element with id "overlay" has got display:none; , meaning the popup might be displaying, but it's parent is not. Try replacing:

```
$('#popup').show();
```

with:

```
$('#popup, #overlay').show();
```

Another problem could be that the Javascript is executed before the browser added the element with id "popup" to it's DOM. Try replacing:

```
checkCookie();
```

with:

```
$(function () { checkCookie(); });
```

Comment: I dont believe it is nested, no. Infact im sure it isnt. I tried both your suggestions but it still isnt showing the pop up anymore

Comment: Actually ignore my last comment. Its now showing, but its showing at the top of the page above the header rather than as a pop up. Which has me even more confused

Comment: i have concluded that it might be an issue with the CSS, as everything else appears to be working correctly